# Is there any way to decrypt a .crypt8 file from my Android Phone?

Tags: java, android, python, encryption, cryptography

TL:DR at bottom.

So thing is, I'm currently trying to create a bot to interact with from whatsapp. The bot will be in a slave phone running whatsapp and a background service of my creation.

The problem I'm currently facing is trying to read the whatsapp messages themselves. I tried through notifications by getting the Notification itself as a parced AccessibilityEvent but this seems to have stopped working as of Android 4.2 and I'm currently running Android 5.0 .

My next idea was to check the whatsapp encrypted database (crypt8) and simply decrypt it and have it return the data I wanted. Problem is I can't find any way to do so straight from my phone. All answers I've been getting are along the lines of "download X program and you will see it" or "Nop, that's impossible." 
So... this seems like something very doable as the encryption can be bypassed as seen by the many programs that do it. I also found many examples covering this topic with crypt5 and crypt6, unfortunately I have crypt8 though.

So, what can I do to get the data I want? The phone is rooted if that helps a bit.

If it is literally impossible from the phone I can leave the slave phone hooked to a Raspberry Pi that could maybe access the SD card in the phone and get the crypt8 file from there, then decrypt it and send it back.

Please help me if you know a way!

TL;DR: I need a way to read crypt8 from my rooter phone. Thanks.

Comment: read this http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/101492/is-it-possible-to-decrypt-msgstore-db-crypt8-file

Comment: @VividVervet Thank you for answering. I had seen that link before but I'm looking for a way to access the database and returning the information in a way readable to a program. The goal isn't simply for me to be able to read the info, it's to do something from that info that would've been gotten automatically.

Comment: Not really, since it doesn't answer the question completely.